# Converting XML to dataframe in R studio

Tags: r, xml

I am not a coder, but trying to learn R. I have scraped these jobs from indeed and need in dataframe for analysis. My file is [here](http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8693092939388569&q=data+scientist&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=2000&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=in&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2)

However I used this code:

```
install.packages("XML")
library("XML")
library("methods")
results <- xmlParse("http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8693092939388569&q=data+scientist&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=2000&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=in&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2", isURL=TRUE)
print(results)
rootnode <- xmlRoot(results)
rootsize <- xmlSize(rootnode)
print(rootsize)
> print(rootsize)
[1] 10
```

My problem starts in the following code(I think, the argument is not doing well):

```
xmldataframe <- xmlToDataFrame("http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8693092939388569&q=data+scientist&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=2000&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=in&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2")
print(xmldataframe)

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c("Indian Council Of Medical Research (ICMR) Needs ScientistIndian Council of Medical Research (ICMR)INIndiaEmployment SamacharThu, 18 Aug 2016 16:16:15 GMTIndian Council Of Medical Research (ICMR) Needs Scientist. Indian Council of Medical Research (ICMR) invites applications to recruit on vacant posts of...http://www.indeed.co.in/viewjob?jk=20d1db3c7d973199&qd=704PFtVAS6xUi0-OukCaEmfxgGzxqabhMKv0iphFlwZvghJwQWAysomG7BsaL67IpeRHLNudzQ_v_UGEGMFYq0JvivwR6g0dNKs-MyZMxww&indpubnum=8693092939388569&atk=1arpjr78d5upddvtindeed_clk(this,'6618');20d1db3c7d973199falsefalsefalseIndia16 days ago",  : 
  duplicate subscripts for columns
> print(xmldataframe)
Error in print(xmldataframe) : object 'xmldataframe' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `xmlToDataFrame()`, you need to first parse the XML document and then reference document and the repeated elements that will serve as your rows. Fortunately, the XML is not heavily nested to require data transformation/wrangling needs.

```
library("XML")

# PARSE DOCUMENT FROM URL (paste0 used to break up line for readability)
results <- xmlParse(paste0("http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8693092939388569",
                           "&q=data+scientist&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=2000",
                           "&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=in&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4",
                           "&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2"), isURL=TRUE)

# CONVERT TO DATA FRAME ON <result> NODE
df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(results, "//results/result"))
```

Screenshot output *(25 obs of 19 vars)*:

[image: XML dataframe result]

Comment: Thanks, this def helped Parfait.

Comment: Great! Also, it's customary on SO to accept the answer that most helped you to confirm resolution.

Comment: Hey thanks I am new to stackoverflow. I think I did accept it as an answer now by ticking the check mark. Let me know if I didnt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xml2` and `purrr` to do that as follows:

```
require(xml2)
require(purrr)
doc <- read_xml("http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8693092939388569&q=data+scientist&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=2000&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=in&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2")
html_table(doc)
doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//results/result") %>% 
  map(xml_children) %>% 
  map_df(~map(setNames(xml_text(.), xml_name(.)), type.convert, as.is=TRUE))
```

Comment: I had never used purr before. Will look into its functionality more.